# Changing texture of a SpriteKit node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have an object that includes a SpriteKit node:

```
class PauseButton{
    var playTexture: SKTexture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "play")
    var pauseTexture: SKTexture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "pause")
    var node: SKSpriteNode

    init(){
        self.node = SKSpriteNode(texture: pauseTexture)
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to change its texture via SKAction, but nothing happens:

```
pauseImage.node.runAction(SKAction.setTexture(pauseImage.playTexture))
```

I also tried to run `self.scene!.view!.setNeedsDisplay()`
 to no avail.

Comment: The only thing to keep in mind between changing a texture directly vs changing the textrue using an SKAction is timing. SKActions are queued and executed in the next frame while changing the texture propert should take effect immediately. setNeedsDisplay is not needed here. Nodes are presented by the scene, not by the view. There is a big difference how views and nodes are rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    var playTexture: SKTexture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "play")
    var pauseTexture: SKTexture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "pause")
    var node: SKSpriteNode
    let changeTextures = SKAction.animateWithTextures([pauseTexture], timePerFrame: 0.1)
    node.runAction(changeTextures)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an`SKAction` for that. Use the `texture` property instead. It's the exact same as if you use the `SKAction` but much easier to use and to understand:

```
pauseImage.node.texture = pauseImage.playTexture
```

Also you don't have to use `SKTexture.init` just use:

```
SKTexture(imageNamed: "play")
```

Comment: I already tried changing it by simply doing <code>pauseImage.node.texture = pauseImage.playTexture</code> before, but nothing showed up. Sorry for not saying it. And changed the .init, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a class that is used to represent a node, I used `self.run(SKAction.setTexture(ballTexture))`.

If you aren't using the same usecase as I am, then you'd just use `nodeName.run(SKAction.setTexture(ballTexture))`

Cheers.